# How to get int instead string from form?

Tags: php, html, string, variables, int

Getting variable from form:

```
<form method = 'POST' action = ''>
        <input type = 'text' name = 'a' size = '1' >
        <input type = 'submit' value = 'Find it'>
</form>"
```

If I enter 1 and use gettype($POST_['a']) it returns me string, is it possible to enter int? because after this I want check if that variable is int.

**UPDATE**

Got answers that it returns always string and they offered me to use (int) or intval(), but then if it's really string like 'a' it returns 0, but it may be also integer value 0, how to overcome this problem?

**UPDATE**

After editing typo Brad Christie suggested best way, using is_numeric

Comment: There's a lot of questions like this on SO that show up in my interest list because they have the tag HTML. It's not really an HTML question it's a PHP question. Should I be de-tagging HTML?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
// convert the $_POST['a'] to integer if it's valid, or default to 0
$int = (is_numeric($_POST['a']) ? (int)$_POST['a'] : 0);
```

You can use [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to check, and php allows casting to [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) type, too.

For actual comparisons, you can perform [is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php).

**Update**

Version 5.2 has [`filter_input`](http://php.net/filter_input) which may be a bit more robust for this data type (and others):

```
$int = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'a', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

I chose `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`, but there is also `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` and [a lot more](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)--it just depends what you want to do.

Comment: `$_POST['a']` will **never** be an `int` so `$int` will _always_ be zero with this.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Freudian slip on my part, I was thinking of is_numeric. Good catch, and I'll correct.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: I initially used is_int, which is why the down vote. Thanks to @AndrewMarshall it was caught. -- @Templar: figured as much, and you're very welcome. ;-)

Comment: What if the posted object is an array of strings that should be integers, like a <select multiple="multiple" name="ids[]">? Do I need to iterate and convert each entry to int or is there a better method?

Comment: @David You can use [`array_map`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to do so: `array_map('intval', $_POST['ids'])`

Comment: Also worth noting in case you need boolean and are passing it over the wire as 0 and 1 that in php `(bool)'0' === false`

Answer (score 19):

Sending over the wire via HTTP, *everything* is a string. It's up to your server to decide that "1" should be `1`.

Answer (score 5):

No. HTTP only deals with text (or binaries).

You have to convert it.

Comment: `int` is not  method. `intval($a)` or `(int) $a`

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `(int)$_POST['a']` to convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

if you prefer mantain a wide type compatibility and preserve input types other than int (double, float, ecc.) i suggest something like this:

```
$var = is_numeric($_POST['a'])?$_POST['a']*1:$_POST['a'];
```

You will get:

```
$_POST['a'] = "abc"; // string(3) "abc"
$_POST['a'] = "10"; // int(10)
$_POST['a'] = "10.12"; // float(10.12)
```

Comment: Yes, we might send floating numbers too ;)