# php pagination getting error (Fatal Error:unspported operand types)

Tags: php

I got an Error **Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in line12** while doing pagination in my page. Please help me how to solve this

```
<?php
 require_once("pagination.php");
    $page=1;//Default page
    $limit=1;//Records per page
    $start=0;//starts displaying records from 0
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']!=''){
    $page=$_GET['page'];
    }
    $start=($page-1)*$limit;
    ?>
```

Comment: Which is **line no. 12**?

Comment: on line 12: $start=($page-1)*$limit

Comment: Make sure that $page and $limit are type of numeric.

Comment: i have declare as a integer?

Comment: @user2637639 PHP does only know the `mixed` type. So you need to make sure `$_GET['page']` only contains numbers. You do that by adding `is_numeric($_GET['page'])` to your `if` statement.

Comment: check it right before the line 12

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$start = (is_numeric($page) ? (int)$page : 0)*limit;
```

[How to get int instead string from form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052932/how-to-get-int-instead-string-from-form)