# else if returning true when false

Tags: php, html, if-statement

Im trying to figure out why my elseif statement is returning the else if $name < 5 true even tho I enter fields greater than 5 , it should be echoing out "Great" if all are false! I set the $name and $score var to '' because im using this in the html values which i dont want to error undefined,  new to php thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php



$name = '' ;
$score = '' ;
$message = '';

if (isset($_POST['name'])){

 $name = $_POST["name"];
 $score = $_POST["score"];

 if (!$name || !$score) {

    $message = "Please fill in both name and score!";

 } elseif ($name < 5) {

   $message = "name must be at least 5 characters";


 } elseif ($score < 5) {

     $message = "score must be at least 5 characters";

 } else {

   echo 'Great';

 }

}



?>



<h1>Enter Your info </h1>
<hr>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" value="<?  php echo $name;  ?>"> <br>
    Score: <input type="text" name="score" placeholder="Enter Score" value="    <?php echo $score;  ?>">
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">

</form>
<p class="error">
  <?php echo $message ;  ?>
</p>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean `strlen($name) < 5`?

Comment: @u_mulder x-file closed ;)

Comment: What do you think `'Fred' < 5` should evaluate to? string less than integer?

Comment: thanks , i forgot about that lol

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions No w3schools plz! :)

Comment: OK,  just try `pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"` on the inputs! Lookup HTML-input attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$name < 5
$score < 5
```

They both are strings and the output would be undesired. To check the lengths, change them to:

```
strlen($name) < 5
intval($score) < 5
```

And as mentioned in the comments, this is a mistake:

```
value="<?  php
```

There shouldn't be any spaces.

Comment: And note him about this part too ` value="    <?php ` trolling whitespaces ;)

Comment: trolling whitespaces ?

Comment: @MarkeseP See my edited stuff... You have a space before `php`

Comment: @MarkeseP Score being posted as integer, I am just converting the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Visit ([How to get int instead string from form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052932/how-to-get-int-instead-string-from-form)) basically you are comparing a string with a number,
it should be made to an int

```
$int = (is_numeric($_POST['a']) ? (int)$_POST['a'] : 0);
```