# How to calculate using a POST variable?

Tags: php

I need to multiply this POST variable by 12.  As an example, if the amount was 10, the result should say:

```
Amount: 120
```

Here's my code so far:

```
Amount :'.$_POST['my_amount'].'<br/>
```

I tried to run the calculation in another variable, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
$result = ($_POST['my_amount'])*12;
```

or maybe it works and my output code is not working:

```
 $vl_text='';
        Amount :'.$_POST['my_amount'].'<br/>'.;
```

Comment: "but this doesn't seem to work" It should work this way. Did you output the `$result` variable?

Comment: That should work already

Comment: probably your $_POST['my_amount'] does not have what you expect. try var_dump($_POST['my_amount']) to show it's content.

Comment: worked fine for me `$_POST['my_amount'] = 10;
echo $result = ($_POST['my_amount'])*12; ` - Total: 120.

Comment: this could be failing for a multitude of reasons. But we won't know that till you post your full code.

Comment: print your $result varible!

Comment: actually, it probably does work, but I need the output into this HTML which is probably what is failing: function send_email_to_user($user, $sender) {    $vl_text='';
    if(($_POST['contribution']>0) && ($_POST['pay_type']=='onetime')) {
        $vl_text='<br/>
        My Amount :'.$result.'<br/>

Answer (score 0):

If you want your output to resemble your first example.,..   Amount:120 your missing chunks in each of the following 3 examples. first ensure that your $_POST variable is a valid one and set it to a new variable so you can print out the variable if you need to ...

```
// if you only expect $_POST['my_amount'] to contain integers...

if(is_int(intval($_POST['my_amount']))){
    $my_amount = intval($_POST['my_amount']) * 12;

// or if you expect $_POST['my_amount'] to possibly contain a decimal

if(is_float(floatval($_POST['my_amount']))){
    $my_amount = floatval($_POST['my_amount']) * 12;
```

intval ensures that a variable is cast as an integer if it can be, while not entirely necessary as multiplying in php will do this...its good practice to check any variables that you are using for and math functionality.
floatval does the same for for numbers with decimal. as an integer has to be a whole number if your variable could numbers that could contain decimals... use floatval

all of your examples then need to specify to print/echo the string....so

```
// your second line
echo 'Amount :'.$my_amount .'<br/>';
// your fourth line...
$vl_text='Amount: '.$my_amount;
echo $vl_text;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The most logical explanation is that you get string from POST. A good way to achieve what you want is to convert the POST value to int but keep in mind that it could not be numerical.

```
$int = (is_numeric($_POST['my_amount']) ? (int)$_POST['my_amount'] : 0); //If POST value is numeric then convert to int. If it's not numeric then convert it to 0
```

Comment: looks very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052932/how-to-get-int-instead-string-from-form)...

Comment: *Numerical* does not necessarily mean `int`. The number could be a floating point; thus losing information by casting to an `int`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$_POST['my_amount'] = 150;
$data = $_POST['my_amount'] * 12;
echo $data;
```

Result will be `1800`