# Can a radio input send an integer to Django with POST?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, input, radio-button

I'd like to give three choices which are represented by words but are going to POST numbers:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="intensity" id="Low" value=1 autocomplete="off"> Pale
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="intensity" id="Medium" value=5 autocomplete="off"> Medium
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="intensity" id="High" value=9 autocomplete="off"> Deep
      </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

But then in my view `request.POST.get('intensity')` is a string. Do I need to manually convert it or there's something I'm missing?

ps. I'm not using Django forms and I don't want to use it at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. HTTP only deals with strings and the value of the string is left for the server to decide. You can convert the value using [int() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) in python.

Reference:
[How to get int instead string from form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052932/how-to-get-int-instead-string-from-form)