# how to avoid refresh on a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, html

when I use a drop down menu to select a quantity on a e-commerece based cart app, the drop down menu refresh to 1 after making the necesari changes on the variables. 
the cart will change the quantity for the item and the price acordingly BUT will refresh itself and show 1 despite of the change on the rest of the variables.

here is my code:

```
    <table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>ITEM NAME</th>
<th>QUANTITY</th>
<th>UNIT PRICE</th>
<th>ITEMS TOTAL</th>
</tr>   
<?php       
foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $product){
?>
<tr>
<td>
<img src='<?php echo $product["image"]; ?>' width="90" height="80" />
</td>
<td><?php echo $product["name"]; ?><br />
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='hidden' name='code' value="<?php echo $product["code"]; ?>" 
/>
<input type='hidden' name='action' value="remove" />
<button type='submit' class='remove'>Remover</button>
</form>
</td>
<td>
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='hidden' name='code' value="<?php echo $product["code"]; ?>" 
/>
<input type='hidden' name='action' value="change" />
<select name='quantity' class='quantity' onChange="this.form.submit()">
<option <?php if($product["quantity"]==1) echo "selected";?>
value="1">1</option>
<option <?php if($product["quantity"]==2) echo "selected";?>
value="2">2</option>
<option <?php if($product["quantity"]==3) echo "selected";?>
value="3">3</option>
<option <?php if($product["quantity"]==4) echo "selected";?>
value="4">4</option>
<option <?php if($product["quantity"]==5) echo "selected";?>
value="5">5</option>
</select>
</form>
</td>
<td><?php echo "R$".$product["price"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "R$".$product["price"]*$product["quantity"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$total_price += ($product["price"]*$product["quantity"]);
}
?>
<tr>
<td id="td_tot" colspan="5" align="right">
<strong>TOTAL: <?php echo "R$".$total_price; ?></strong>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>





and here is the head section:

    $status="";
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="remove"){
if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $key => $value) {
      if($_POST["code"] == $key){
      unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$key]);
      $status = "<div class='box' style='color:red;'>
      Produto Removido</div>";
      }
      if(empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
      unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
      }     
}
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="change"){
  foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as &$value){
    if($value['code'] === $_POST["code"]){
        $value['quantity'] = $_POST["quantity"];
        break;
    }
}

}
?>
```

I need to make it stay showing the last selection instead and after several tries and looking out on internet for an answer I only can rely on this comunity to help me. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace onChange to onBlur.
It will not update unless click outside of select menu.

Comment: that make the refresh happen when I click outside the drop box, I do want the refresh happening "onChange" so the values for the variables will change. the thing is I need the number showed on the dropbox AFTER the refresh to be the las number selected and NOT "1", my problem is that after the refresh the value for the dropbox displays "1" even if the user chose some other number and the prices changed accordingly.

Comment: After a lot of research I found out that my problem was a syntax one, when I tried to identify the active variable I wrote <?php echo "selected" ?>  and It should be <?php echo 'selected="selected"' ?>

Answer (score 0):

Because of [Sending over the wire via HTTP, everything is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052946/3125033), you have to use `==` instead of `===`. See [php operator here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp)

Comment: that will make it return true if the variables are identical, ... I don't see how it may help me.

Comment: can you var_dump($_SESSION['shoping_cart']) after changing to except 1 ? Check for the code value type if it is an integer then <code>$value['code'] === $_POST["code"]</code> will never return true